# Debian, IPv6 is not asssigned to interface

Tags: networking, debian, interface

I have a Debian 7 Server with several networks and KVM VMs running configured:

- 2a01:4f8:191:439b::/64
- 144.72.132.208/29

The IPv6 Subnet is splitted into /96 Networks to assign each bridge a own subnet.

`auto hetzner0
    iface hetzner0 inet static
        address 144.76.43.151
        network 144.76.43.128
        netmask 27
        gateway 144.76.43.129
    iface hetzner0 inet6 static
        address 2a01:4f8:191:439b:0:0:0:1
        netmask 96
        gateway fe80::1
    auto hetzner1
    iface hetzner1 inet static
        address 144.72.132.209
        broadcast 144.72.132.208
        netmask 29
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_fd 1
        bridge_waitport 0
        bridge_stp off
    iface hetzner1 inet6 static
        address 2a01:4f8:191:439b:0:1:0:1
        netmask 96`

While IPv4 is working perfectly, IPv6 is making me crazy. The v6 Address on hetzner0 is assigned correctly and I am able to ping arround the world. But the address on hetzner1 is not getting assigned! I am able to add it manually by doing the following:

```
/sbin/ip -f inet6 addr add 2a01:4f8:191:439b:0:1:0:1/96 dev hetzner1
```

While this working, doing this in a post-up and pre-down hook does not work...

```
post-up /sbin/ip -f inet6 addr add 2a01:4f8:191:439b:0:1:0:1/96 dev hetzner1
pre-down  /sbin/ip -f inet6 addr add 2a01:4f8:191:439b:0:1:0:1/96 dev hetzner1
```

IPv6 is enabled for this Interface via sysctl, while the most automatic configuration is disabled:

`╰─$ sysctl -a | grep 'hetzner1'
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.accept_local = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.arp_accept = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.arp_announce = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.arp_ignore = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.arp_notify = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.bootp_relay = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.disable_policy = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.disable_xfrm = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.igmpv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.igmpv3_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.medium_id = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.promote_secondaries = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.proxy_arp_pvlan = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.route_localnet = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.secure_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.shared_media = 1
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.src_valid_mark = 0
net.ipv4.conf.hetzner1.tag = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.hetzner1.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.hetzner1.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv4.neigh.hetzner1.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv4.neigh.hetzner1.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv4.neigh.hetzner1.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv4.neigh.hetzner1.locktime = 100
net.ipv4.neigh.hetzner1.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.hetzner1.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv4.neigh.hetzner1.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv4.neigh.hetzner1.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.hetzner1.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv4.neigh.hetzner1.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv4.neigh.hetzner1.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.accept_dad = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.accept_ra_defrtr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.accept_ra_pinfo = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.dad_transmits = 1
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.force_mld_version = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.force_tllao = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.hop_limit = 64
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.max_addresses = 16
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.max_desync_factor = 600
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.mldv1_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.mldv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.mtu = 1500
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.ndisc_notify = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.optimistic_dad = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.proxy_ndp = 0
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.regen_max_retry = 3
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.router_probe_interval = 60
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.router_solicitation_delay = 1
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.router_solicitation_interval = 4
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.router_solicitations = 3
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.suppress_frag_ndisc = 1
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.temp_valid_lft = 604800
net.ipv6.conf.hetzner1.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.hetzner1.anycast_delay = 100
net.ipv6.neigh.hetzner1.app_solicit = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.hetzner1.base_reachable_time_ms = 30000
net.ipv6.neigh.hetzner1.delay_first_probe_time = 5
net.ipv6.neigh.hetzner1.gc_stale_time = 60
net.ipv6.neigh.hetzner1.locktime = 0
net.ipv6.neigh.hetzner1.mcast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.hetzner1.proxy_delay = 80
net.ipv6.neigh.hetzner1.proxy_qlen = 64
net.ipv6.neigh.hetzner1.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.hetzner1.ucast_solicit = 3
net.ipv6.neigh.hetzner1.unres_qlen = 31
net.ipv6.neigh.hetzner1.unres_qlen_bytes = 65536`

I am desperate, does anyone has a solution for me?

Victor

***UPDATE:***

I'm embarrassed but while i was clicking randomly throuh the links on the right side, searching for a similar problem to mine i found this:

[IPv6 only works after pinging the default gateway.](https://serverfault.com/questions/477471/ipv6-only-works-after-pinging-the-default-gateway?rq=1)

The following lines got my attention(yes, my provider is Hetzner Germany):

> Because Debian is crazy for not already having that in there? –  Michael Hampton♦ Feb 23 '13 at 9:29
>
> The file was provided by hetzner: "### Hetzner Online AG - installimage" But it is definitely my fault, not seeing it in the first place :D. –  dexstar Feb 23 '13 at 9:31

So i tried his solution and it finally worked! I added to /etc/network/interfaces while the install image of Hetzner does not provide this:

```
iface lo inet6 loopback
```

Comment: I added the solution to my Problem under "Update".

Comment: Glad you resolved this. You should post your update as an answer and [mark it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able.